# Placing Bootstrap Dialog Model inside webpage

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I used Bootstarp modal in my website, but  when i try to fire this modal with button click

```
<input type="image" name="ImageButton4" id="ImageButton4" class="bw" data-target="#pnlModal" data-toggle="modal" src="Images/note.png" onclick="javascript:return false;" style="width:15%;" />
```

> it show inacative model as this picture ! [image: in active modal]

And this is my Model `CSS` code which exist inside bootstrap.cs`

```
 </div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlModal" runat="server" role="dialog" CssClass="modal fade">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlInner" runat="server" CssClass="modal-dialog" >
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlContent" CssClass="modal-content" runat="server">
                <asp:Panel runat="server" class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Write Your Note Now ! we'll save it in "D" partition </h4>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:panel runat="server" class="modal-body">
                  <asp:TextBox ID="NoteText"  TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="form-control" Font-Size="Larger" Font-Bold="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 </asp:panel>
                <asp:panel runat="server" class="modal-footer">
                    <asp:LinkButton  OnClick="Button1_Click1" ID="Button1" runat="server"  CssClass="btn btn-success"  >Write Now ! </asp:LinkButton>
                </asp:panel>
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
```

and this all modal markup

```css
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: 0;
}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-out;
       -o-transition:      -o-transform .3s ease-out;
          transition:         transform .3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
      -ms-transform: translate(0, -25%);
       -o-transform: translate(0, -25%);
          transform: translate(0, -25%);
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
          transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
          background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
          box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000;
}
.modal-backdrop.fade {
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal-backdrop.in {
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .5;
}
.modal-header {
  min-height: 16.42857143px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.modal-header .close {
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.modal-title {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}
.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.modal-footer .btn + .btn {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.modal-footer .btn-group .btn + .btn {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.modal-footer .btn-block + .btn-block {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.modal-scrollbar-measure {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: I faced this issue. try this 1. update the latest css or  2.Place the `modal` div outside of all content i.e just before body close tag . and if this doesn't work then provide a fiddle with rendered html

Comment: @JSantosh Thanks for you time , but i cannot place it out side ! .. it muse be placed inside <form runat="server" > Right ?

Comment: ohk, then provide a fiddle with rendered html

Comment: @JSantosh there is a modal start with page load .. http://ahmedibrahhim-001-site1.smarterasp.net/Control.aspx?Key=OqQgabnOKz2bmId4

Comment: @JSantosh can you check it ?

Comment: this is same issue i faced . the modal must not be inside the regular content, i must be at end . so if you can update the entire code for control.aspx , i can say where to place it , that's the only solution i got. there is definitely some other code after this modal in page control.aspx. so copy this entire modal code and place it the end of the control.aspx file after all other code.

Comment: @JSantosh i did that and place it at the end of my code .. but it seemed to be not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90123/discussion-between-ahmed-ibrahim-and-j-santosh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously your `.modal` element is positioned *under* the `.modal-backdrop` element. By default their `z-index`'es is

```css
.modal-backdrop {
   z-index: 1040;
}
.modal {
   z-index: 1050;
}
```

Something in your code / CSS elsewhere has broken this default order. Reintroduce the z-order by adding the above CSS *after* bootstrap.css and other CSS declarations.

---

**Update**. You can place it as the last thing just before `</head>` or before `</body>` if it not is working :

```
<style type="text/css">
.modal-backdrop {
   z-index: 1040;
}
.modal {
   z-index: 1050;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you sir ,but i'm very beginner with `bootstrap` models ,  and your answer is very clear but i cannot understand it ! .. should i change `z-index:1040` which inside  button ? or  put it inside css models ?

Comment: i'm very grateful  , but can i keep in contact with you out of stackoverflow because it may consider as chat here

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim, it is rather late in the evening here, but if you want to share a link just add it in a comment, then I get it and you can delete that comment afterwards.

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim Can you share a link? It should defently work, no matter what - an odd alternative is if the modal container is within an element with fixed or relative position, but cannot tell without seeing the markup and CSS. Can you add the complete markup to your question, the markup that is rendered - not the ASP?

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim Have translated your asp markup and included the CSS -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ga8hrpnn/** it works fine, so it is something in the sorroundings of the modal element causing the problem.

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim please dont Sir me :) I try to see if I can spot anything out, just delete your comment.

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim, I will go further with this in the morning, it is 1.30 am here. I have really never seen something like this before, only once I succeded to get it right - but cannot get it right. PS - you should place the first code from <doctype> to <html> into <head>. It is not the reason for anything, I guess - browsers are very forgiving, it is just bad markup :)

Comment: i tried it with diffrent machin but it still did not work :((

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90124/discussion-between-ahmed-ibrahim-and-davidkonrad).